How to calculate roll and pitch of robot's base-link frame using IMU data in ROS2?
I want to calculate the roll and pitch of a robot's base-link frame relative to the ground using ROS2. My robot has two IMU sensors, one at the front and one at the rear, each providing linear acceleration in the x, y, and z directions. The sensors are mounted on a horizontal arm such that it can moves up and down and one sensor is located up and another one is located down. The sensors oriented with a 180-degree difference in the x and y axes around the z-axis. I've already calculated the roll and pitch of each sensor relative to the horizontal plane using the acceleration values (using the formula below). Additionally, I have the rotation matrix between each IMU sensor's frame and the robot's base-link frame (using tf2). What steps and formulas should I use to determine : 1) the roll and pitch of each imu sensor in base-link frame, and 2) the roll and pitch of the base-link frame relative to the horizontal plane (ground) by averaging the roll and pitch of both sensors?
roll = atan2(linear_accel.y, linear_accel.z);
pitch = atan2(-linear_accel.x, sqrt(linear_accel.y * linear_accel.y + linear_accel.z * linear_accel.z));

I appreciate any help in advance.
Abbas
